# Unable to Access SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have registered an Application on Azure and I am trying to get an access token using the following command.

`$Auth=Get-ODAuthentication -ClientId 01xex4x7-f0e2-xbx4-8aa3-1ac7a46c784c -AppKey "Xm1234~x555Sr-ATtpyCBOzkYiakI.PCVkEuBZ" -RedirectURI "http://localhost/login" -ResourceId "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/" -RefreshToken $LastAuth.refresh_token` .

I am getting the following error.

> Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an
> empty string. At
> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\OneDrive\2.2.7\OneDrive.psm1:127
> char:47
>
> - ... thentication | add-member Noteproperty $element.split("=")[0] $elemen ..

However, when I save the command to a script and add a timeout, I am able to get the access token.
I have set the REDIRECT URI as `http://localhost/login` (Not an actual working URL). Can this be the reason. I tried to look this up but a little confused about the value this should have. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @NIREN GUPTA, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?,

Answer (score 0):

***We have tested the same in our environment to access the sharepoint by using powershell and it works fine at our end. Below is the workaround :-***

- *Register an application in *Azure AD* , Added *redirect uri* as `http://localhost/` and enabled ID token .*

[image]

- ***Given the below permissions to our application and granted admin consent in Azure Ad.***

[image]

- *Installed the one drive module by using* `Install-Module -Name OneDrive -Scope CurrentUser -force`
- Used the below command to get the access token after login with `connect-azaccount` , ***Ensure that you have provided all the permissions as mentioned above and added the correct resource ID of your sharepoint application and redirect uri as followed.***

`Cmdlt`:-

```
  $Auth=Get-ODAuthentication -ClientId "60xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -AppKey "3aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=" -RedirectURI "http://localhost/" -ResourceId "https://mytest-admin.sharepoint.com/" -RefreshToken $LastAuth.refresh_token
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS :-***

[image]

***POWERSHELL VERSION:***

[image]

For more information please refer this [***GitHub| OneDrive for Business***](https://github.com/MarcelMeurer/PowerShellGallery-OneDrive/blob/master/readme.md#onedrive-for-business)